# Fetching error while parsing in JSON

Tags: json, parsing, firefox, fetch

I developing a web client in ReactJS and an API in Java. I use fetch to get information from my server. Everything is working except that the parsing of the result in JSON. I got this error in firefox:

> JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

and in chrome :

> unexpected end of input

Actually, I looked inside the response (that Firefox received) and the body, the content-type are good. I tried with Postman, and it's working well.

Here is my code:

```
return fetch("http://localhost:8080/API/users")
.then((res) => res.json()).then((users)) => (console.log(users));
```

Is there anything that I do wrong? Or should I do it differently for Firefox?

My back end should normally send this kind of response :

```
[
    {
        "lastname": "name1",
        "firstname": "firstname2",
        "pseudo": "pseudo3",
        "id": 1
    },{
        "lastname": "name2",
        "firstname": "firstname2",
        "pseudo": "pseudo2",
        "id": 2
    }
]
```

res is equal to :

> Response =  {
>       bodyUsed: false,
>       headers: Headers = {  },
>       ok: false,
>       redirected: false,
>       status: 0,
>       statusText: "",
>       type: "opaque",
>       url: "", }

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the response returned by your back-end.

Comment: It "should normally" send that kind of response. What else might it send? When the error is generated, what value does `res` have?

Comment: Sorry, forget the "normally".